# Conjugation rule for "enclitic pronouns"?

Tags: pronombres, conjugación, enclisis

While reading some materials, I found words like these: "conocerte" (= te conozco), "mirarte" (= te miro).

I can't effectively find anything useful (in English) about this.

What's the exact name of this conjugation and is there corresponding rules for conjugations about "me/te/lo/la/nos/los/las conozco"?

---

Excuse me for being new to Spanish. Please don't write the whole answer in Spanish or I'll have trouble understanding it

Comment: while someone has time for a full answer let me say that "mírate" is not "te miro (I'm looking at you) " but it means "look at yourself". Also check if you are asking about "conoceRte" or "conócete" since the first one is "I know you" while the second is "know yourself" (similar to _mírate_). Or perhaps you are asking about "miraRte" which indeed is used when "I'm looking at you"

Comment: @DGaleano Corrected my question. I mean "I know / am looking at you", not "know / look at yourself".

Comment: Here's the super simple version: "Yo quiero conocerte" = "Yo te quiero conocer."  It's just a fun way of moving the pronoun over and sticking it onto the end of the infinitive.  Try reading them out loud and you'll see that the "conocerte" version is a fun variant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A full answer would require the equivalent of a few Spanish course classes, so I'll just clear the basics up.

What you found are combinations between verbs and pronouns. These are not different conjugations. The pronouns are the shorter, unstressed, non-empathic forms that are technically known as *clitic*. A pronoun is *enclitic* if it's attached to the end of the verb, and *proclitic* if it's attached before the verb. (Proclitic pronouns in Spanish are not written together with the verb, but they're attached to it nevertheless: they behave as if they were part of the same word.)

There are a number of rules dictating when a clitic pronoun can and cannot precede or follow a verb. These can get fairly complicated but here are some:

- Clitics never precede infinitives: it's *conocerte*, never **te conocer*.
- Clitics may precede or follow conjugated verbs (except in the imperative), but in modern Spanish they usually come before: *la miro* is OK and *mírola* is OK too, but nobody says *mírola* nowadays.
- Clitics always follow verbs in the imperative: it's *mírame* and *vete*, never **me mira*, **te ve* (note: these sound exactly the same as other forms of the verb which are not imperatives).
- Clitics also follow the gerund forms: *mirándolos*, *yéndome*, *conociéndonos*.
- If there are two clitics (because the verb takes two objects), the first is always the indirect object: it's *te lo diré* or *decírtelo*, never **lo te diré* or **decírlote*.

As I said, these are not different forms of the verb (conjugations), in the same way as *him* in *I see him* is not part of the verb: you just need to learn the verbs by themselves and then learn how to properly place the pronouns.

Comment: Sobre el punto _Clitics always follow verbs in the imperative_, recuerdo haber oído en Colombia expresiones del tipo _se mire el codo, que le está sangrando_. Es decir, que sí usarían el clítico antes del imperativo. No sé si se considerará incorrecto.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Hablarías inglés, por favor? No puedo entenderte mucho.

Comment: @iBug dije: about _Clitics always follow verbs in the imperative_, I remember hearing expressions like _se mire el codo, que le está sangrando_ in Colombia. That is, they using the clitic before an imperative. I do not know if that is incorrect.